# Wordpress Plugin firing twice on front page but firing once on admin

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a plugin that counts user visits and saves the IP, date, and count of visits.
In DB have id(big int), IP(str), visits(int) and date(DATE).
my code in the plugin main file is this:

```
if (is_admin()){
    include WPS_INC . 'back-end.php';
}else{
    include WPS_INC . 'front-end.php';
    do_action('wps_update_db');
}
```

the code in front-end.php

```
function wps_user_visits_count(){
    global $wpdb;
    $tp = $wpdb->prefix;
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $ip = intval($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
    $is_user_visited_site_today = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT `id`
                                                        FROM `{$tp}wps_user_visits` 
                                                        WHERE `date` = '{$today}' AND `ip` = {$ip}");
    if (empty($is_user_visited_site_today)){
        $wpdb->insert($tp . 'wps_user_visits',
        array(
            'ip' => $ip,
            'date' => $today
        ),
        array(
            '%d','%s'
        ));
    }else{
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE `{$tp}wps_user_visits`
                      SET `visits` = `visits` + 1
                      WHERE `id` = {$is_user_visited_site_today}");
    }
}

add_action('wps_update_db','wps_user_visits_count');
```

and it will add 2 visits in DB instead of one.
in this line `` SET `visits` = `visits` + 1 `` for example, if I change 1 to 3, it will add 6 visits instead of 3.

how can I solve this problem?

I also use `$wpdb->update`. no change.

Comment: then you call the function twice besides the ip is problematic because more than one can have the same public ip

Comment: Could you please explain how I called the function twice? There are 2 problems actually! in the wp admin, it will count the visit but it added 1 and in the front-end, it counts twice.

Comment: your cod ewill increase the number if user id by one, so if you get 2 you runwps_user_visits_count twice, i can't tell you where and when as i don't know your code. you can enable general log in mysql and see what queries run against the server and you will see there are 2 updates. another problem is your approach, as ip number are basicaly unique, but because of NAT you can share the public ipadress, so your select will not get the right id, because many ids can have the same ipadress

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, but it didn't work again. I used the query monitor plugin to check the queries. The function wps_user_visits_count is being called only once. When I echo something after `$wpdb->query` inside `else` it will also echo once and I literally checked if it is the admin page or not, but it will count the visits also on the admin page.
I also changed the $ip to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Comment: as i said enable general log, to see what the server sees.

Comment: Thank you for responding to this question.
My Problem Solved BUT I have no explanations for that. I was using wampserver virtual host ((plugin.course)) and when I deleted it and get back to ((localhost/plugin_course)) problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was **NOT** with the code.

The problem was with the **Wampserver**.

So if you are using wampserver, get a backup of your database and www folder and then DELETE wampserver using REVO UNINSTALLER. It's so important using this program for uninstallation.

After the first step of uninstallation, you should delete all left-overs using the Revo uninstaller.

After that, you can easily install wampserver and you are good to go.

**I should say that I was using a virtual host too. So if you used it, my answer will probably help you.**

If you are using another local host program such as XAMP and Laragon, try this solution.